# How to change a Do loop to a For loop?

Tags: procedural-programming

I'm a rookie in the loops. I would like to use a For loop to get a solution like using a Do loop.

```
Do[Print["a[", i, ",", j, "]=", If[j != 4, i + j, -100]], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 2, 6, 2}]
a[1,2]=3
a[1,4]=-100
a[1,6]=7
a[2,2]=4
a[2,4]=-100
a[2,6]=8
a[3,2]=5
a[3,4]=-100
a[3,6]=9
a[4,2]=6
a[4,4]=-100
a[4,6]=10
```

I have tried to do something like this but I am not getting the correct result.

```
For[i = 1; 
 For[j = 1; j != 4, i + j, -100; j = j + 2; 
  Print["a[", i, ",", j, "]="]; {j, 2, 6, 2}]; i++, {i, 1, 4}]
```

Comment: `For[i = 1;` you put a semicolon here and in multiple places on the next line - Mathematica `For` loops aren't C/C++/Java, instead you use commas.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? For loops are among the least useful way to program in Mathematica. Also, what is the point of all the print statements... you are essentially setting a matrix of values, why not display using MatrixForm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [`While`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/245093/363) version . . .

```
For[i = 1, i <= 4, i++,
 For[j = 2, j <= 6, j += 2,
  Print["a[", i, ",", j, "]=", If[j != 4, i + j, -100]]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding @bills's notion:

`TableForm@Table["a["<>ToString@i<>","<>ToString@j<>"]="<>ToString@If[i!=4,i+j,-100],{i,1,4},{j,2,6,2}]`

If you do not like the columns, you can `Flatten` the matrix.